# Как вывести переданное значение JSON в PHP типа name[0][amount]?

Tags: php, json

Через Ajax передаем данные в формате JSON, на сервере принимаем в create.php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

и получаем к примеру:

```
{
"name": "",    
"description": "\u043f\u043f\u043f\u043f\u043f",
"created": "2023-09-16",
"category_id": "1",    
"name[0][amount]": "100",
"name[0][price]": "20"
```

$data->name; выводит верное значение " ".
Как вывести значение name[0][amount]  ?

Comment: $data->name[0][amount];  - это не верно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два варианта:

1. Обратитесь к свойству объекта таким образом:

```
$data->{'name[0][amount]'}
```

2. Раскодируйте json в ассоциативный массив:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

Тогда можно будет обратиться к элементу как:

```
$data['name[0][price]']
```

Ну и самый простой вариант -- изначально формировать нормальный json